# Complicated Pigeonhole Principle Homework Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

There are $n$ participants in a tournament, where $n \geq 1$. In matches in the tournament, there is a clear winner and clear loser (no ties). A participant $x$ is a "champion" if for all other participants $y$, either $x$ directly beat $y$ or $x$ directly beat some third participant $z$ who beat $y$. Prove that at least one of the $n$ participants will be a "champion".

I'm fairly certain this question requires some application of the Pigeonhole Principle, but I'm really not sure where to start. Any help would be really appreciated!

Edit: Each person will play against every other participant exactly once.

Comment: How many rounds?  Is it round-robin or is it undefeated goes against undefeated.  Clearly undefeated vs undefeated will satisfy your question so are you assuming round robin with $n-1$ matches each?

Comment: @LarryFreeman Just edited the question—each player plays against every other player exactly once.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: If $x$ is not a champion, there must be some $y$ who beats $x$. Moreover, $y$ must beat everyone whom $x$ beat, because otherwise we’d have $x$ beating some $z$ who beat $y$. Thus, $y$ must beat more people than $x$ beat: all of the ones whom $x$ beat, plus $x$. This should tell you where to look for the champion(s).

Comment: am I on the right track if I say that the champion then can never lose? I'm still a little confused

Comment: @LorenzaFuller: The champion can lose. For instance, if $n=3$, $a$ beats $b$, $b$ beats $c$, and $c$ beats $a$, all three of them are champions.

Comment: Sorry even with your hint/clarification I'm still unsure about how to approach this problem. What would the pigeonholes be in this case?

Comment: @LorenzaFuller: It’s not a pigeonhole principle problem, at least as I’m solving it.

Comment: I'm still fairly stuck—right now I've broken down the problem into two cases. Case 1: Everyone is a karting champion, in which we are done. Case 2: There is a participant x that is not a karting champion. As you said, there must be a participant y who beat x and everyone that x beat. But I'm not sure how to approach with Case 2.

Comment: @LorenzaFuller: Okay; you’ve missed the real point of my hint, which is that no one can have won more matches than a champion. That suggests that the person or people who have won the largest number of matches might be the champions. In fact that’s true; try to use the idea in the hint to show that it’s true.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For each participant $x$, let $B(x)$ be the number of participants $y$ that $x$ either beats directly or for which there is a $z$ such that $x$ beats $z$ and $z$ beats $y$. Now pick an $x$ for which $B(x)$ is maximal. Prove that $x$ is a champion.

The pigeonhole principle is not used here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pick an x for which $n(x)$ is maximal? Wouldn't that just be n-1?

Comment: I changed the notation to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Take a player $p$ who won a maximal number of matches -- say, $m$.  I claim they're a champion.

To prove that: suppose there is a player $q$ who beat $p$.  We need to show that there exists a player $r$ such that $p$ beat $r$ and $r$ beat $q$.

So, in search of a contradiction, suppose that's not the case.  Then necessarily, $q$ beat all $m$ players that beat $p$.  However, since $q$ ALSO beat $p$, we see that $q$ won at least $m+1$ matches -- contradicting the assumption that $p$ won the most matches of any player.